# Install BeautifulSoup for another Python version on Mac OS X

Tags: python, installation, beautifulsoup

I have three versions of Python on my Mac: 2.6.1 (built-in), 2.5.4 (Google App Engine development), and 2.7.2 (general Python programming).

I installed BeautifulSoup with `python setup.py install`. However, only 2.7.2 is able to work with it.

How do I install it for 2.5.4 as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/path/to/other/python setup.py install
```

It can be helpful to make aliases for your various system Pythons (e.g. `python25`, and so on) in your `.bashrc`.

In regards to changing what `python` points to from the default system Python, I know that this will work if you alias to a *newer* version, but it may cause issues with an older version, so be careful (just my $.02).

Comment: Thanks. I used `python2.5 setup.py install`

Answer (score 1):

Set your `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable to point to the installation you want to install it for, and make sure you're using that version of Python when you run `python setup.py install`. Something like `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python25 /usr/bin/python25 setup.py install`.